# How do i setup Stackblitz with Angular 16 and jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, stackblitz

With the intention of asking a different question about Angular+Jasmine, I wanted to reproduce my failing code in StackBlitz for better reference.

There are many working examples of how to achieve this (e.g. [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-with-jasmine) or [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jasmine-in-angular))
which more or less follow the same structure as found in [this guide](https://lukasznojek.com/blog/2019/05/add-jasmine-unit-testing-support-to-angular-in-stackblitz/).  However, all the examples and templates I have found use rather old versions of Angular. Updating any of these examples within StackBlitz to Angular 16, by pressing the ↻ *Update All to Latest* button will break them, resulting most of the time in following error:

```
Error in polyfills.ts
The entrypoint for 'zone.js' could not successfully be resolved.
The file '/turbo_modules/zone.js@0.14.0/dist/zone' does not exist.
```

I found out [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zone.js?activeTab=readme), that
replacing `import 'zone.js/dist/zone';` with `import 'zone.js';` might solve this problem.

However, after that i just get the next error, that i can't figure out to fix:

```
Error in main.ts
The entrypoint for 'jasmine-core' could not successfully be resolved.
The file '/turbo_modules/jasmine-core@5.1.1/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js' does not exist.
```

When i try to `import jasmineRequire from 'jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core.js';` in WebStorm, I get the following error:

```
TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module  jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core.js
```

and advises to declare the module in a *.d.ts file.

I tried to do that in `src/jasmine.d.ts`, but it didn't help.

My attempts to reproduce my actual problem  (which I will ask about in another question once I have solved this problem) can be found [here on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/jbrell-dev/stackblitz-angular/tree/develop?file=src%2Fmain.ts). I have commented out the failing parts, so you can see, that the project compiles up to the point where I try to use jasmine.

I don't know if these problems are related or not, and if this should be split into multiple questions.

I have already found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56943261/how-to-setup-jest-with-angular-in-stackblitz), which only leads to one of the outdated examples I referenced earlier.

*Note*:  I am very new to web development and this is my very first question on a StackExchange site. I hope the quality of my question isn't too bad.

***Summary***: How do I get the same result as seen in the outdated examples I referenced, but with Angular 16 in a project setup as seen in my Stackblitz setup?

Comment: Take my fork : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-jasmine =)

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Thank you. Although I have not (yet) been able to adapt your solution to my project setup, it has given me some insight into what configuration options I might want to take a closer look at.